# React Webpack creating boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to make react boilerplate with webpack with this tutorial 
[enter link description here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75)

But getting an error when trying run the code (npm run start). I'm getting the error when reaching the section -> Setting up webpack-dev-server
. Error message is this[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you lack the `@babel/core` npm package...

This is a classic example of when to do exactly what the error message is telling you to do. This took me A VERY LONG TIME to figure out as a developer, and I still waste time NOT following the directions on screen from time-to-time... So you are not alone if this is indeed the case.

The first issue in the error message that you have control over, is a missing `@babel/core` package in your `node_modules/` directory. I say try satisfying the dependency by installing the package exactly as specified.

I'm sure you know how to do so already, but for clarity's sake, you'll want to enter the following command into your terminal prompt, from your project's root directory:

```
$ npm i @babel/core
```

after it's finished installing, re-enter `$ npm run start` and see if that fixed it.

If it doesn't, and the error message doesn't change, my only other idea would be to install babel-loader@7 like the error message is telling you to do.

```
$ npm i babel-loader@7
```

If it doesn't fix it and a new error is displayed, repeat the process until your dependencies are worked out.

Or, you can also move or rename your `node_modules/` directory and enter `$ npm i` to rebuild your package dependencies.

make sure to keep your original `node_modules/` folder handy though, just in case you need it. Once you have everything running, you are free to get rid of it.

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install --save-dev @babel/core` then try building again.